# Does a node's behaviour change when it is a member of a struct?

Tags: c, nodes

I'm trying to learn how to use linked lists, so I've written myself a function to recursively go through a linked list and print a word stored in each node, but it's only printing the penultimate item and then repeating indefinitely. I've debugged this and I can see it's because the last node will satisfy `n.next != NULL`, so I wanted to change the condition to `n != NULL` to avoid this, but I get the error message: `error: invalid operands to binary expression ('node' (aka 'struct node') and 'void *')`. I've tried to search the error message on Google and SO but I can't explain why `n.next != NULL` compiles nicely but `n != NULL` doesn't. To me, I'd say `n` and `n.next` are both type `node`, but presumably my intuition is deceiving me somehow. Is it because `n.next` is a `struct` `member` that it's behavior changes, or am I on the wrong track?

I include the code below (function in question is at the bottom):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node
{
    char word[20];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

void print (node n);

node *table[1];

int main(void)
{
    // TODO
    char word[20];

    FILE *file = fopen("list", "r");
    node *first = malloc(sizeof(node));
    table[0] = first;

    if (file != NULL)
    {
        while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
        {
            node *entry = malloc(sizeof(node));
            if (entry != NULL)
            {
                strcpy (entry->word, word);
                entry->next = first->next;
                first->next = entry;
            }
        }
    }
    
    print(*first);
}

void print (node n)
{
    while(n != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", n.word);
        print(*n.next);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try passing a `node *` to `print` instead of a `node`.

Comment: Thank you @dbush :) My program now prints everything in the list. Although it now prints the final word infinitely- I had expected it to stop, as I thought the last node would point at `NULL`.

Comment: What's the value of `first->next` when you first enter the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To me, I'd say `n` and `n.next` are both type `node`

Not so; `n` is a `node`, but `n.next` is type `node *`, i.e. a pointer to a `node`.  Pointers can be null but structs cannot.

Thus the object passed to `print` is guaranteed valid.  (If `first` were a null pointer then `print(*first)` would already have crashed, or "caused undefined behavior", before you even entered `print`.)

It's also not necessary to have a loop in `print`, since the recursion handles the list traversal.  Indeed, if you try to keep the loop as it is, it's an infinite loop, because nothing in the body modifies the value of `n`.

I would write:

```
void print (node n)
{
    printf("%s\n", n.word);
    if (n.next != NULL)
        print(*n.next);
}
```

However this approach is not really idiomatic, and it's also not very efficient, since passing `struct`s by value tends to involve unnecessary copying and stack usage.  It'd be more common, as dbush suggests, to have a version that takes pointers:

```
void print(const node *np)
{
    if (np)
    {
        printf("%s\n", np->word);
        print(np->next);
    }
}
```

which you then call as `print(first);`.

A next good exercise would be to try to write a version of `print` that doesn't use recursion, since that will allow you to handle very long lists that might exceed your stack size.

Comment: Hi Nate, would a non-recursion version be an iterative one?

Comment: @Oustriste: Right, with a loop.

Comment: I thought `if` and `while` functions were loops?

Comment: `while` is a loop, as are `do/while` and `for`. But  `if` is not a loop; it executes various blocks of code either once or not at all, but never more than once.  (And none of them are functions, they're control structures.)  Your original version did have a loop, but it also had recursion, and more to the point it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

there are mainly to problems:

1. don't forget to initialize the value after malloc, or they can be anything, especially the next will not be NULL as you expected.

```
    node *first = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    first->word[0] = '\0';     
    first->next    = NULL;
    node *entry = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    entry->word[0] = '\0';
    entry->next    = NULL;
```

I prefer to use calloc than malloc

```
node* first = (node*)calloc(1, sizeof(node));
assert(first);

node* entry = (node*)calloc(1, sizeof(node));
assert(entry);
```

2. in the function of print

```
    void print (node* n)
    {
            if(n != NULL)
            {
                    printf("%s\n", n->word);
                    print(n->next);
            }
            
    }
```

since you call print recursively, if should be used rather than while